# Command prompt can't write letter by letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
def textinput(txt,waittime=0.04):
    end = len(txt)
    letters = 0
    while end != letters:
        print(txt[letters], end = '')
        letters += 1
        time.sleep(waittime)
textinput('Hello there!')
```

This is basically my function for writing words letter by letter, it works flawlessly on IDLE when testing it, however, when I run it normally (and it opens up the command prompt), what I'm trying to write stays invisible, and then suddenly displays the words at once. Did I type something wrong, or is it command prompt's issue? I'm using windows 10.

Comment: What is happening if your program stuffs characters into the stdout buffer. At a point, the OS decides to flush the buffer, and you see all the characters at once. To get the single char at a time effect, you must explicitly flush the buffer after each character is written, as in @PadriacCunningham answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to use `sys`, you just need `flush=True`:

```
def textinput(txt,waittime=0.4):
    for letter in txt:
        print(letter, end = '',flush=True)
        time.sleep(waittime)
```

You can also simply iterate over the string itself.

Comment: This totally makes things easier to write and understand! I didn't even know there was a built in code for this... (and why isn't flush true by default?)

Comment: @PopCar,  usually output is line buffered, because you set end = `""` is the only reason you need to flush, usually the default behaviour is what you would want

Answer (score 10):

Output is probably buffered, trying flushing it by adding the following line after your print:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I guess I'm not one for system commands...
p.s: You forgot to mention I should import sys first, but lucky I already knew that part as soon as I saw this.

Comment: `print()` can do the flushing *for you* with `flush=True`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue most probably is the the standard output is not getting flushed automatically instead it is getting buffered, for your case to work, you should manually `flush()` stdout -

```
import time
import sys
def textinput(txt,waittime=0.04):
    end = len(txt)
    letters = 0
    while end != letters:
        print(txt[letters], end = '')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        letters += 1
        time.sleep(waittime)
textinput('Hello there!')
```