# Why time() below 0.25 skips animation in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, stdout

This code works as expected. Output:

```
Loading 
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
```

Code:

```
done = False
count = 0

while not done:
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading"),
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading."),
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading.."),
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading..."),
    time.sleep(0.25)
    count += 1
    if count == 5:
        done = True
```

And this code doesn't. Output:

```
Loading.
Loading...
```

Code:

```
done = False
count = 0

while not done:
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading"),
    time.sleep(0.125)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading."),
    time.sleep(0.125)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading.."),
    time.sleep(0.125)
    print '{0}\r'.format("Loading..."),
    time.sleep(0.125)
    count += 1
    if count == 5:
        done = True
```

Why does the time function seem to skip every second `print` statement if it is lower than 0.25?

Comment: Strange, it works on my machine. Maybe it's OS-dependent. I'm on Windows 7. What operating system are you on?

Comment: I don't have this problem, I get `Loading
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...`, but it's likely to do with your carriage returns.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm and Windows 10

Comment: It seems to be related to output buffering and the effects will vary a lot on different machines. It didn't print anything at all on my machine, for example. :-)

Comment: I'm just getting `>>> ing...` :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233636/command-prompt-cant-write-letter-by-letter/32233850#32233850

Comment: Update: yep, it's output buffering indeed. So essentially this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Comment: If you import the print function or switch to Python 3, you can just use `flush=True` instead of making explicit calls to `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that's good tip thanks!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: You can't use the `__future__` import to get `flush=True` support in Py2; the `flush` argument was only added to the `print` function in Py 3.3, and never backported to the 2.x line.

Comment: Tested and got `TypeError`... looks like you're quite right. That's too bad. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reason

Depending on the platform, Python buffers the output to different degrees.
For example, on Mac OSX there is no output at all even for your version with 0.25 seconds sleep.

### Flushing manually

Flushing manually should work:

```
import sys
import time

done = False
count = 0

while not done:
    for n in range(4):
        print '{0}\r'.format("Loading" + n * '.'),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.125)
    print ' ' * 20 + '\r',
    count += 1
    if count == 5:
        done = True
```

You need to flush the output with `sys.stdout.flush()`. You also need to print empty spaces to make the dots "going back and forth":

```
print ' ' * 20 + '\r',
```

### More minimal and cleaned up

This is shortened and a bit more general in terms of the shown text:

```
import sys
import time


text = 'Loading'
for _ in range(5):
    for n in range(4):
        print '{0}\r'.format(text + n * '.'),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.25)
    nspaces = len(text) + n
    print ' ' * nspaces + '\r',
```

### Running unbuffered from the commandline

You can remove the line:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

if you run your script with the `-u` option:

```
python -u script_name.py
```

**Note**: This will have an effect on all `print` statements.

Comment: Instead of printing 20 spaces it might be cleaner to use the terminal size: `width = struct.unpack('HHHH', fcntl.ioctl(0, termios.TIOCGWINSZ, struct.pack('HHHH', 0, 0, 0, 0)))[1]`

Comment: @ThiefMaster Looks pretty complicated to me. Isn't `print '  ' * nspaces + '\r',` a bit simpler? I use it my cleaned-up version.

Comment: hrm yeah, in this case it's easier for sure. In a real application you'd put it as a `term_size` function in a util module or even provide a `clear_line()` function that prints \r and the right number of spaces

Comment: It doesn't work in PyCharm but it works in Python so it should be fine. Thank you for help and explaining this to me.